# Python Check if object is ListProxy or DictProxy

Tags: python, multiprocessing, typing

I'm using the multiprocessing module in python, and using the shared variable lists and dicts provided by the mp manager.

```
import multiprocessing as mp    
a = mp.Manager()

b = a.list()
b
<ListProxy object, typeid 'list' at 0x14098207908>

c = a.dict()
c
<DictProxy object, typeid 'dict' at 0x140984579c8>
```

I want to do:

```
if isinstance(b, ListProxy):
    do something
elif isinstance(c, DictProxy):
    do something else
```

However these don't seem to be built in types, I've tried checking them against the base list and dict types but they obviously didn't work

How can I test for these types in the code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def judge(x):
    if isinstance(x, mp.managers.ListProxy):
        print('It is a ListProxy.')
    elif isinstance(x, mp.managers.DictProxy):
        print('It is a DictProxy.')
    else:
        pass
    pass

def main():
    a = mp.Manager()
    b = a.list()
    c = a.dict()
    judge(b)
    judge(c)
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from multiprocessing.manager import ListProxy, DictProxy

if isinstance(b, ListProxy):
    do something
elif isinstance(c, DictProxy):
    do something else
```

You can just import them from where they were defined, which is in the manager modlue

Comment: I'm not sure you can, when running: 
from multiprocessing import manager
I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'manager' from 'multiprocessing' (~\.conda\envs\tpoc\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py)

Also tried importing the 'Manager' class, but i get 'No module named 'multiprocessing.Manager'

Comment: you shouldn't import the `manager` module, you should import the list and dict from it, exactly like it is in the first line of my code

Comment: When typing your code exactly as it is, I get this: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'multiprocessing.manager'`

Comment: @Hansang add an 's' in manager. Try doing `from multiprocessing.managers import ListProxy, DictProxy`